# Auto scoring sales calls

Tags: regression, survival, topic-models

I am not a statistician so pardon any incorrect technical term usage. I have learned just enough to know I don't know anything but am trying to understand the problem before engaging a real life analyst.

This question is probably a little too broad but for the scenario below what approach would you use?

I am trying to automatically score how well a sales person follows a sales script. I have clean transcripts from the sales person's conversations with customer and fairly structured order of topics and key words they should be covering. Humans are not perfect, though, and will often say the right things but perhaps with slightly different words or slightly different order than expected. However, the entire scope of the sales script is fairly contained

The most important aspects of the scoring is

- Were topics covered in correct order?
- Were all topics hit?

Long term I would also like to start predicting a sale based off these factors along with others.

I have hundreds if not thousands of recorded interactions that I could use to train a model with help from QA team members.

I have received recommendations ranging from manually creating key word look ups to various regression models to Survival Analysis.

Comment: In my opinion, it is not just 'reading' a sale script that leads to a successful sale, but how 'read' (fast/slow/voice tone) and what feeling was successfully communicated to the target buyer. The latter point may or may not result in a sale, but based on a customer's verbal response (positive or negative, a suggested dummy variable), may be better correlated with actual sales. As such, my auto rating on score how well a salesperson performed would include a reading time score (not too short or too long) along with a customer's verbal response, positive or negative, suggested dummy variable.

Comment: A good script should also be interesting, original, even funny but most importantly project confidence in the product. Do mention the popularity of the product, ease of use, potentially multiple uses, expected longevity, limited supply and/or expiring but a currently available discount.

Comment: Interesting prediction task. You will find the online web service by 'Insight Classifiers' valuable for your purpose. You need to build a key word predictor, followed by a time series model.